# Как сделать классификацию?

Tags: r, статистика

Мне нужно произвести классификацию, использую логистическую регрессию.

тестовые данные и обучающая выборка задаются вот так:

```
train = data.frame( x1 = c(1,2,3), x2 = c(3,4,5), y = c(1,1,0))
test = data.frame( x1 = c(1,2,5), x2 = c(1,3,5))
```

Как это реализовать кодом?

Я пытался, но в итоге вылезали баги

```
mldata <- mlogit.data(train, choice = "y")
formula = as.formula(paste("y ~ ", "x1+x2"))
mlogitModel = mlogit(formula, mldata)
pred = preict(mlogit_model, test)
```

Answer (score 3):

Для проведения классификации с помощью логистиче5ской регрессии можно воспользоваться функцией `glm()` с аргументом `family = binomial(link = "logit")`. Для получения вероятности отнесения наблюдений к тому или иному классу используется функция `predict()`.

```
fit <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = train, family = "binomial")
pred <- predict(fit, newdata = test, type = "response")
```